# xauth twitter on iphone app

Tags: iphone, twitter, xauth

I will use xAuth to post data on my twitter account and I'm kind of stuck with the signature, header stuff.

I have the following code:

```
    // Build url
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?x_auth_username=%@&x_auth_password=%@&x_auth_mode=client_auth",
                 x_auth_username,
                 x_auth_password];

// Signature
NSString *oauth_nonce = @"";
NSString *oauth_signature_method = @"HMAC-SHA1";
NSString *oauth_timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSString *oauth_version = @"1.0";
NSString *x_auth_mode = @"client_auth";

NSString *sig = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token&oauth_consumer_key=%@&oauth_nonce=%@&oauth_signature_method=%@&oauth_timestamp=%@&oauth_version=%@&x_auth_mode=client_auth&x_auth_password=%@&x_auth_username=%@",
                 oauth_consumer_key,
                 oauth_nonce,
                 oauth_signature_method,
                 oauth_timestamp,
                 oauth_version,
                 x_auth_mode,
                 x_auth_password,
                 x_auth_username];

// Encode signature
NSString *encodedSig = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)sig,NULL,(CFStringRef)@"/:+,=&",kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
NSLog(@"encoded signature:%@",encodedSig);

/*
    NSData *dSecret = [secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *dBase = [base dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
uint8_t result[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmacContext hmacCtx;
memset(&hmacCtx, 0, sizeof(hmacCtx));
CCHmacInit(&hmacCtx, kCCHmacAlgSHA1, dSecret.bytes, dSecret.length);
CCHmacUpdate(&hmacCtx, dBase.bytes, dBase.length);
CCHmacFinal(&hmacCtx, result);
*/

// Headers
NSString *header = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OAuth oauth_nonce=\"%@\", oauth_signature_method=\"%@\", oauth_timestamp=\"%@\", oauth_consumer_key=\"%@\", oauth_signature=\"%@\", oauth_version=\"%@\"",
                    oauth_nonce,
                    oauth_signature_method,
                    oauth_timestamp,
                    oauth_consumer_key,
                    oauth_signature,
                    oauth_version];

// Perform HTTP request
[Helpers httpPostWithString:encodedUrl];
```

I do not really see how to :
- encode the signature
- attach the signature and header to the request

Could you please help ?

Thanks a lot,

Luc

Comment: what is signature in twitter oauth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? There are plenty of existing XAuth and OAuth libraries out there for you to use.  [link text](http://github.com/rentzsch/OAuthConsumer)

Comment: I just want to be able to issue 2 https requests, I do not need / want to use other libraries (that are sometimes hard to integrate).

Comment: suit yourself. But when it is all over, ask yourself which approach would have taken less time to integrate.  Also, which approach has been community tested?

Comment: totally aggree with you. I just wanted to understand the thing, sometimes lib do much more than once need.

Comment: Ok, well, you made me change my mind and give another try to Aral's xAuthTwitterEngine. One linking error t solve in xcode and that should be ready for testing :) I'll let you know (if you want :) ).

Comment: Aral updated his now that MGTwitterEngineDemo has been updated to use XAuth. He recommends not to use xAuthTwitterEngine anymore.  See https://github.com/aral/MGTwitterEngineDemo

Comment: Also be aware that if you want to be able to post to Twitter with the same instance of the Twitter engine from various view controllers for example, you'll probably want to keep it in a central place like a singleton and pass delegate/selector references.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple library from Eric Johnson [twitter-xauth](https://github.com/ericjohnson/twitter-xauth)

Answer (score 0):

There's some working Twitter xAuth sample code at http://bitbucket.org/brentsimmons/rstwittercallgetxauthaccesstoken/src.

As it says at that page:

> It turns out that the OAuth/xAuth
>   stuff isn't hard -- you just have to
>   get the details right.